# C# - Prevent animation of a showing form

Tags: c#, forms, animation

Is there any way of stopping the default opening animation of a form from Windows? I mean stopping it just for one form, not all of them. I need the showing of a form to be instantly, without that growing effect.

I tried to document about WinApi, but I couldn't find anything. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take a couple of steps to achieve this:

In the constructor, set your `BorderStyle` to `None`. This will prevent the animation:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
}
```

Of course, now you want to show the border again, so you have to set it back as soon as your form is shown, so the user never sees this. Therefore create a method:

```
private void Form_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
}
```

Now you have to set the `Shown` event of your form to your `Form_Loaded` method. You can do this from the form designer event properties window.

If you want to do it for the entire application you can change it using the [SystemParametersInfo Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I need it to be borderless even after displaying it. Thank you anyway, I solved my problem. Check out the answer!

Comment: If you don't need the border you can skip the second part and only add `this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;` to the constructor!

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the location property after showing the form. It works!

```
this.Hide();
this.Size = this.Size;
this.Location = this.Location;
this.Show();
```

Comment: For me this still shows an animation when I open the form.